# Glassfish active directory realm authentication occasionally reverts to file realm authentication

Tags: authentication, active-directory, glassfish

We are running Glassfish 3.1.2.2 authenticating against an Active Directory realm.  Authentication works correctly the vast majority of the time, but occasionally, authentication will suddenly start failing for all users, and we'll see errors like this in the server log:

```
[#|2014-03-19T21:37:32.331+0000|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.web.security|_ThreadID=1098;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WEB9102: Web Login Failed: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: Failed file login for jeff.|#]
```

Note that the error message is failed *file* login.  It appears as if Glassfish is occasionally reverting back to the file realm rather than the active directory realm.

When this problem happens, after a short time without any intervention on our part, authentication will suddenly start hitting Active Directory again and users will be able to login again.

Any ideas why Glassfish would occasionally revert to authentication against the file realm when we've configured it to use Active Directory?  Should I delete the file realm altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally determined the trigger for this.  We had been connecting JVisualVM to our Glassfish instance to monitor performance.  Everytime I connect JVisualVM (over JMX connection using Glassfish admin credentials), Glassfish immediately reverts to using the file realm instead of the LDAP realm.  I have no idea why JVisualVM would cause this behavior in Glassfish, but it is consistently reproducible.  The only workaround I have discovered is:

1. Disconnect JVisualVM.
2. In Glassfish admin console go to -> Configurations -> server-config -> Security
3. Change default realm (to anything other than LDAP realm), Save.
4. Change default realm back to LDAP realm, Save.
5. Clients should now again be able to authenticate against LDAP.